# How to listen Ajax events on an Ajax triggering element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, events

In my HTML document I have this code:

```
<a id='ajax-trigger' href='...', data-one='...'>
  Trigger AJAX!
</a>
```

And in a external, not my own and uneditable JS library I have something like this:

```
$('#ajax-trigger').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: a.attr('href'),
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // handle Ajax success...
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // handle Ajax error...
    }
  });
});
```

With the above code in place, when the `<a>` link is clicked then the Ajax request is triggered.

Now, to further manipulating the DOM after a success Ajax response, I'm looking for a way to listen the success Ajax response local event related to the Ajax triggering element without changing the JS library source code. That is, I would like to add an Ajax success event listener for the `<a>` element in the HTML document without changing the original JS library. Maybe, something like this (note: `ajaxSuccess` is just an example):

```
<a id='ajax-trigger' href='...', data-one='...'>
  Trigger AJAX!
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ajax-trigger').on('ajaxSuccess', function() {
      // handle Ajax success in addition to the 
      // Ajax success handler in the JS library...
    });
  });
</script>
```

Is it possible with jQuery/JS?

Comment: Simply use trigger method to trigger the event on the element you want. https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @Akxe See comments to the current answer

Comment: Yeah... you don't know, nor want to accept what is library’s code and what is yours. Without change to code behavior cannot change. Period, learn basics, or at least accept help. This is purely frustrating

Comment: @Akxe Maybe I don't understand you. What is what i.e. JS library’s code and my code is described in the question. I'm open to learn, hence to accept help. Sorry if this is frustrating

Comment: Everything in your post is user code. It is code made by you. Library’s code is this https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js the is the source code for jquery (as of now)

Comment: @Akxe To a good connoisseur a few words.

Answer (score 0):

Using just your code and adding pure JS - solution 2 answers your question.

Btw.: why do you need to add this event/event listener? If you want a function to be executed after your successful ajax call, all you need to do is call the function as part of your $.ajax success

Solution 1:

```
$('#ajax-trigger').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: a.attr('href'),
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // handle Ajax success...
      myAjaxSuccessFunction();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // handle Ajax error...
    }
  });
});

function myAjaxSuccessFunction() {
    //do some stuff
}
```

Solution 2: fire an actual event on the element, and have a listener on the element for that kind of event.

```
//create the event
var myAjaxSuccessEvent = new Event('AjaxSuccessEvent');

//attach the event to the HTML element
var myHTMLelement = document.getElementById('my-element');
myHTMLelement.addEventListener('AjaxSuccessEvent', function() {
    //do something
    alert("Event fired");
});

//or attach the listener like this, in your case
$('#ajax-trigger').on('AjaxSuccessEvent', function() {
  // handle Ajax success in addition to the 
  // Ajax success handler in the JS library...
});

//fire the event after successful AJAX call
$('#ajax-trigger').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: a.attr('href'),
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // handle Ajax success...
      myHTMLelement.dispatchEvent(myAjaxSuccessEvent);
      var myElement = document.getElementById('ajax-trigger');
      myElement.dispatchEvent(myAjaxSuccessEvent);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // handle Ajax error...
    }
  });
});
```

Solution 3: without the custom event
You can't add an event listener unless there's an actual event you're subscribing to.
If you don't want to add a custom event, you'll have to fire one of the existing events.

```
//fire the event after successful AJAX call
$('#ajax-trigger').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: a.attr('href'),
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // handle Ajax success...
      // use an existing event
      var getMyElement = document.getElementById('ajax-trigger');
      getMyElement.onchange();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // handle Ajax error...
    }
  });
});

$('#ajax-trigger').on('onchange', function() {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: (BTW Answer: It is because I "cannot" and "want to avoid" editing the original JS library) How your solutions would make listen Ajax events on the Ajax triggering element without changing the JS library source code? Is it possible?

Comment: yes, it's possible. you can use this with the normal JS library. if this answers your question, please upvote / accept the answer. thanks!

Comment: you mean, you want to do this without
var myAjaxSuccessEvent = new Event('AjaxSuccessEvent'); 

The changes I made are not changes to the JS library source code. They are using what the library already provides us, adding custom events.

If you don't want to add a custom event, then attach an event listener to one of the normal events and dispatch that event.

I'll edit the answer.

Comment: No, I mean not to add `myAjaxSuccessFunction` in _Solution 1_ and not to add `myHTMLelement.dispatchEvent(myAjaxSuccessEvent); [...]` in _Solution 2_ to avoid changing the JS library source code.

Comment: So, after the update, your answer includes _Solution 3_: "You can't" :|

Comment: It seems you are confusing what it means to "change js library source code". Adding code to what the js library already provides is not "changing source code".

It seems what you're asking is not possible - you can't fire an "ajaxSuccess" custom event if there's a listener for it, unless you add a custom event and then trigger that event. Because there is no automatic event that would fire on any html element after a successful ajax call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209640/discussion-between-brodev-and-backo).

Comment: With "changes to the JS library source code" I refer to changes to pre-built/made JS library such as jQuery. And I want to avoid changes to the JS library source code that I'm using. Adding code to JS library such as jQuery means to change its source code. 
Maybe it's the other way around.

Comment: You don't need to change the JS library to implement the answer, neither do you need to add jQuery code. The code added in solution 1 and 2 is pure javascript, except where the listener is added with "on". But there is another listener with normal javascript on myHTMLelement

Comment: In Solutions 1 and 2 the code related to `$('#ajax-trigger')` (which is part of the JS library) changed, as described in my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685326/how-to-listen-ajax-events-on-an-ajax-triggering-element/60686882?noredirect=1#comment107370984_60686882